# MQTT cant use, what i am doing wrong? i remove configure at this sudo nano mosquitto -c

Tags: mqtt

```
1569015975: mosquitto version 1.6.6 starting
1569015975: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.confv2.
1569015975: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1569015975: Error: Cannot assign requested address
```

Comment: You need to EDIT the question to give a lot more detail of what you are actually doing here. You should include the content of the `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.confv2` file so we can see what you've changed.

Comment: Also please read the documentation about how to ask a good question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because as it stands there is no where near enough information to help here.